# Respond to GET request with image created by Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, canvas

I have a simple Node Api which takes a GET request, constructs a canvas using [node canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas), saves it as a PNG, and sends it back to the server. I'm able to save it, but I cannot return it to the server. The router is:

```
router.get('/canvas', function(req, res) {

    var callback = function(data){

         res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.write('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,')
          res.write(new Buffer(data).toString('base64'));
          res.end('"/>');
    };

    canvas.getCanvas(callback);

});
```

And the Node model is:

```
  var getCanvas = function(callback){

    var Canvas = require('canvas'),
    canvas = new Canvas(150, 150),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    fs = require('fs');


    ctx.font = '30px Impact';
    ctx.rotate(.1);
    ctx.fillText("Awesome!", 50, 100);

    var te = ctx.measureText('Awesome!');
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(50, 102);
    ctx.lineTo(50 + te.width, 102);
    ctx.stroke();


    var out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/text2.png'),
        stream = canvas.pngStream();


    stream.on('data', function(chunk){
      out.write(chunk);
    });

    stream.on('end', function(){
      console.log('saved png');
      fs.readFile(__dirname +'/text2.png', function(err, data) {

          if (err) throw err; // Fail if the file can't be read.

            callback(data);
        });
    });

  }

module.exports.getCanvas = getCanvas;
```

The PNG gets saved to the filesystem, but in the browser response to the GET request i just see:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="/>
```

And the size is only 370 bytes, so the browser is obviously not receiving the image. How can I send this image back as a response to the GET request? And a related question, do I need to save it to the file system or can I somehow stream the image back after it's been created?

Comment: why are you specifying `__dirname` in the write, then deciding to not specify it in the `fs.readFile()` ?

Comment: actually had spotted that and changed it. edited question. this isnt the issue but thanks for pointing out

Comment: also instead of streaming out, then `readFile()` why not just store it in a buffer? IE where you do this `out.write(chunk);` add the chunk to an array, then do `callback(Buffer.concat(array))` in the `on('end'`

Comment: also you are doing `__dirname + 'text2.png'` which will return somehting like `/something/node/foldertext2.png`, you need the seperator

Comment: yeah had added seperator in code! i'll try adding to array

Comment: That seems to work, at least im receiving binary data in angular, just trying to figure out how to display the image now

Comment: You probably just have to tell it it's encoded in base64, don't know anything about angular so can't help you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing to a file, then reading said file, add the chunks to an array and then concat that into a buffer, so change:

```
stream.on('data', function(chunk){
  out.write(chunk);
});
```

to be

```
var chunks = [];
stream.on('data', function(chunk){
  out.write(chunk); //remove this if you have no need to keep file local
  chunks.push(chunk);
});
```

then change your on end to be:

```
stream.on('end', function(){
  console.log('saved png');
  callback(Buffer.concat(chunks));
});
```

and since your callback now accepts a buffer, change this bit as well:

```
var callback = function(data){

     res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      res.write('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,')
      res.write(data.toString('base64'));
      res.end('"/>');
};
```